# Bootstrap blur() not working on label btn

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, label, blur

I have label with class buttons like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">30
   <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</label>
```

And the jquery call back function to blur it does not work:

```
$("label").on("click", function(event) {
   $(event).blur()
})
```

Example page: http://fiddle.jshell.net/e3m62md7/

How to blur the label button when unselected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is by using an Anchor and using a setTimeout:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="AFocus" href="#"></a>
```

**JS:**

```
$.fn.focusWithoutScrolling = function() {
      var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
      this.focus();
      window.scrollTo(x, y);
};
setTimeout(function () { $("#AFocus").focusWithoutScrolling(); }, 10)
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/x8mr1f77/

Without the `setTimeout` I had some issues with Firefox!

I would have preferred to find a cleaner solution...